# Passing variable from JS using ajax to PHP undefined variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to pass variable rating_index to the PHP code and send to database. Rating_index is set I'll not pass the code here because it is long, but right before AJAX i console.log(rating_index) and it has value(int). Add-review is a button that after click should send variable. In js script I am using AJAX :

```
$('#add-review').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url:"rating-data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: {
            rating_index: rating_index
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
           
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
}
```

in my php file rating-data.php:

```
<?php 
    include 'connection.php';
    echo "work";
    echo $_POST["rating_index"];
?>
```

I got a console.log ('work') from PHP file and this error:
Notice: Undefined index: rating_index in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bookwarm-app/rating-data.php on line 4

So it is getting my to php page but the variable are not passing correctly.

I was trying everything and I have no idea what is wrong and why this variable is undefined in php file. Thanks for any clue

Comment: @CBroe I edit post, I have button that after click ajax is running and I got output work because I console log that in PHP file but I also console log the variable and I got undefined

Comment: @evolutionxbox body? what u mean by that?

Comment: Nevermind I though you were using `fetch` and not `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem in your code, sir

```
$user_name = $_GET["user_name"];
$user_rating = $_GET["rating_index"];
$user_review = $_GET["user_review"];
```

you're doing a $_POST request from Ajax and in php file you're getting values from $_GET.....?

Comment: Yes u are right about that it is also a mistake but it is not a solution for my question because as u can see I console log the variable before I run isset so yes I do not get an action from what is going on after isset, but I should get the variable. I edit code

Comment: do `echo "<PRE>"; print_r($_REQUEST);die;` in rating-data.php after echo work.